# JavaScript .search() for a URL with wildcard using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, wildcard, referrer

I'm building a site that is a portfolio of projects. I have some pagination that allows you to go next/previous project.

I want to run some animations when coming to a project, but not when browsing between projects.

My plan is to use the referrer URL to know if you came to a project from another project, and thus not run the animation. But my RegEx is not good, so I'm having trouble.

Here is what I'd like to do (pseudo code)

```
var refURL = document.referrer;
if( refURL.search('http://www.example.com/work/digital/*') > 0 ) {
    // Do not run animation
} else {
    // Run animation
}
```

The important thing, is that "http://www.example.com/work/digital/" should be FALSE, but "http://www.example.com/work/digital/*" should be TRUE.

So, what's the RegEx to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: is * going to be something.html or something.php?

Comment: No it would be http://www.example.com/work/digital/abc/ or http://www.example.com/work/digital/xyz/

Comment: if it's always going to be `digital` , you don't need to use a `regex` I guess. You could just use `split()` method of `javascript` and check if the last 8 characters is `digital/` 

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: And oh,it's not advisable to refer w3schools for everything , but for split , the code in there appears to be fine!

Comment: It's actually not always going to be digital, but that's a good idea to use split!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(.*)` matches 0 or more characters whereas `(.+)` matches 1 or more characters

Also RegExp in JavaScript does not need to be enclosed, so just type

```
var exp = /pattern/modifiers
```

For more details visit: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

My idea for your problem is to try something like:

```
var refURL = document.referrer;
if (refURL.search(/^http:\/\/www.example.com\/work\/digital\/(.+)$/i) >= 0) {
    // Do not run the animation
} else {
    // Run the animation
}
```

Comment: Actually needs to be >= 0 to work. Please update your answer for the future.

Comment: Say I had this: http://www.example.com/work/1234/ or http://www.example.com/work/56/. How would I detect that? /^http:\/\/www.example.com\/work\/(\d{1,10})/?

Comment: yes in general, though be careful about the "www." - use "(www.)?" to tell your pattern to accept both: links with and without "www."! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:-

```
var refURL = document.referrer;
if( refURL.search('http://www.example.com/work/digital/(.*)') > 0 ) {
    // Do not run animation
} else {
    // Run animation
}
```

In other way, you can use `indexOf()`

```
refURL.indexOf("http://www.example.com/work/digital/");

if(refURL.indexOf("http://www.example.com/work/digital/") > -1) {
       // Do Your Stuff
}
```

Comment: You don't need the parens, unless you need to capture what's after digital

Answer (score 1):

can use regex and in javascript

```
var searchin = item.toLowerCase();
var str = "*abc*";
str = str.replace(/[*]/g, ".*").toLowerCase().trim();
return new RegExp("^"+ str + "$").test(searchin);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /^http:\/\/www.example.com\/work\/digital\/.+$/i;
console.log('http://www.example.com/work/digital/x'.search(re));
console.log('http://www.example.com/work/digital/'.search(re));
```